# Sorting by day of week - decode returns null

Tags: sql, sorting, oracle11g

I need to get some data from EMPLOYEES table and create new column with name of week based on hire_date. Results then have to be sorted by day of week (from Monday to Sunday) and that's where is my problem.

I decided to use decode function, but seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my query

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS DAY_OF_WEEK FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY DECODE(DAY_OF_WEEK,'MONDAY',1,'TUESDAY',2,'WEDNESDAY',3,'THURSDAY',4,'FRIDAY',5,'SATURDAY',6,'SUNDAY',7)
```

Everything works well, except sorting. Wednesday is at the beggining and the rest is in random order.

I changed query a little bit, so I could see how this function really works.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS DAY_OF_WEEK, DECODE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'), 'MONDAY',1, 'TUESDAY',2,  'WEDNESDAY',3,  'THURSDAY',4,  'FRIDAY',5,  'SATURDAY',6,  'SUNDAY',7) AS DAY2 FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY DECODE(DAY_OF_WEEK, 'MONDAY',1, 'TUESDAY',2,  'WEDNESDAY',3,  'THURSDAY',4,  'FRIDAY',5,  'SATURDAY',6,  'SUNDAY',7)
```

Something like this returns in column DAY2 number 3 for Wednesday and (null) for everything else.

That's explains why sorting doesn't work, but I still don't know why it's not working and where is an error in the query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the day is padded with spaces.  "Wednesday" matches because it is the longest weekday name.  You could see this if you do:

```
SELECT '|' || TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') || '|'
FROM EMPLOYEES ;
```

If you can live with day of week abbreviations:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY DECODE(DAY_OF_WEEK, 'MON', 1, 'TUE', 2, 'WED', 3, 'THU', 4, 'FRI', 5, 'SAT', 6, 'SUN', 7);
```

I prefer the ANSI standard `CASE` instead of `DECODE()`, but both work in this context.

Comment: You are right! I didn't realize that there are some spaces after names.

As for abbreviations I think they are good enough, so I can use them instead full names :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I always like to know why... the padded spaces explains it.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the logic a bit harder to understand but meets the need.

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions255.htm#SQLRF52058 ..

'IW' Same day of the week as the first day of the ISO week, which is Monday

```
with EMPLOYEES as (
SELECT 'Paul1' First_Name, 'Revere' Last_name, To_date('1-MAR-2016') Hire_Date FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul2', 'Revere', to_date('2-MAR-2016') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul3', 'Revere', to_date('3-MAR-2016') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul4', 'Revere', to_date('4-MAR-2016') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul5', 'Revere', to_date('5-MAR-2016') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul6', 'Revere', to_date('6-MAR-2016') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul7', 'Revere', to_date('7-MAR-2016') FROM DUAL)

SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE
, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
FROM EMPLOYEES 
order by TRUNC (Hire_Date) - TRUNC (Hire_Date, 'IW')
```

Comment: As you don't return the day number there's no need for the `1 +` :-)